# SELECT users by wp_user_level from wordpress database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am developing a desktop application where wordpress tables are used and only Author's level users can login.
here's the query:

```
select u.ID, u.user_login, u.user_email, u.user_nicename FROM wp_users u  
inner join wp_usermeta um ON  um.user_id = u.ID 
WHERE um.meta_key ='wp_user_level' AND um.meta_value='9';
```

is this right query to achieve the intended results?

Comment: Must you use direct Database calls? Are you able to use Wordpress calls?

Comment: you mean this right $wpdb->? I am using Java mate!

Comment: Sort of.... but not exactly, I meant like calling WP functions (eg: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) - But since you are using Java you'll probably need to (.. you didn't mention Java in your question!)... I have always been under the impression that we should try and use direct database calls as a last resort {unless of course what you want to achieve can't be done, or is extremely slow using existing bloated functions}.. Underlying fields and schemas have a habit of changing over time, where as functions and calls generally tend to have more graceful deprecation.